# Visual SourceSafe 6.0 Replacing Same "Unchanged" Project Daily

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

Using Visual SourceSafe 6.0 and Visual Studio 2005. I recently copied a project from one directory. Made changes to it to serve a different purpose. Changed the name of the project and put it in a new directory. I then Added the project back into SouceControl with a new directory. However, every day when I log in and get latest version on the the two projects. All of the files are replaced every day. Even though, no changes have been made to one of the projects in months.

Is there anything that would cause this to happen day after day? Was there a config file somewhere that didn't transfer correctly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My first suggestion would be ["use literally anything other than VSS for source control".](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove source control from a sln you must do the above. From my experience, everything else maybe fail.

1. Remove all `.vsscc` , `.vspscc` and `.scc` files from ALL folders.
2. ReadOnly false all files.
3. Open sln with an editor and remove `GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution` Section.
4. Open each prj with an editor and remove all tags that starting with `Scc`.

Comment: After I copied the folder I went into VisualStudio 2005 and unbound the project from SourceSafe. Maybe I just need to try bridging it again deleting all the files and starting fresh.

Comment: Is not so simple. I use (unfortunately) this tool in my work from 2008. I have done it many times succesful.

Comment: For my projects i use bitbacket and tortoiseHG. But as i said unfortunately i use it in my work.

Comment: You have probably messed up your .ini file of ss.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have access to that.